# Getting key and value from localStorage and displaying it

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I am not getting values, getting only keys. I want take key and values from local storage and display in the paragraph while generating the paragraph dynamically using JavaScript.

```html
<body>
  <p id="para1"></p>
  <p id="para2"></p>
</body>
<script>
  for (var i = 0, len = localStorage.length; i < len; i++) {
    var p1 = document.getElementById("para1");
    var para = document.createElement("P");
    var key = document.createTextNode(localStorage.key(0));
    
    para.appendChild(key);
    p1.appendChild(para);
    console.log("key");

    var p2 = document.getElementById("para2");
    var para2 = document.createElement("P");
    var value = document.createTextNode(localStorage.getitem(key));

    para2.appendChild(value);
    p2.appendChild(para);
    console.log("value");
  }
</script>
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage

Comment: There is no `localStorage.getitem`. Use the [browser console (dev tools)](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/8525) (hit `F12`) and read any errors.

Answer (score 0):

```
var key = document.createTextNode(localStorage.key(0));
```

Maybe this should be

```
var key = document.createTextNode(localStorage.key(i));
```